# How to setup local validator rpc on solscan?

Tags: rpc, validator, validation

I want to check transactions and programs details on my local validator, how can I setup it on https://solscan.io/ ?

I am trying to do it by typing "http://localhost:8899" in "Custom RPC" field, but it is showing an error "The RPC is unavailable!". Solana test validator is running on my PC on 8899 port.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to solscan community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

I was not able to get it done with solscan, even though solscan is offering us  the localhost:8899, it seems not working (at least not on macOS, which I was using).

[solanabeach](https://solanabeach.io) seems to have the same issue.

I got it working with [explorer.solana.com](https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=custom&customUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8899), however.

For some reason, I had to use Firefox to make it work - Brave or Chrome didn't do the trick for some reason.

Great question btw. I feel this is a weird and serious weakness when testing Solana Programs, and should be addressed by Solana Labs in some way.

Comment: Thank you! I used explorer.solana.com and it is working!

Answer (score 4):

Some browsers like Brave blocks localhost access on websites you visit by default. You can either try to use a browser that doesn't block localhost access by default like Firefox or remove the blocker from the browser you are using. In Brave, you can click the Brave icon on the right side of the url bar and choose to remove the shields for the website.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible unless you open your local validator RPC with a endpoint that is publicly accessible (e.g., like genesysgo)

What is the use case here though?

Answer (score 0):

Right now Solscan doesn't support to add RPC from local host since we only change RPC method on backend

Comment: Is it still the case?